# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite model once compiled

Tags: java, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9WWO.png)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXUIK.png)[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TobBj.png)

I am getting this error: `OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite` user `model once compiled.`

Please, resolve this error I'm trying to find by nothing works.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
var fatchuser = require("../middleware/fetchuser");
const Notes = require("../models/Notes");

//ROUTE-1:  Get all the notes: GET "/api/auth/getuser". Login require
router.get("/fetchallnotes",fatchuser , async (req, res) => {
  const notes = await Notes.find({user: req.user.id});
  res.json(notes);
});
module.exports = router;
```

`user` is main problem and `user` value isn't coming.

Comment: Please do not attach your code or errors as images, use code blocks instead (you already did that for some part of your code, why not for all of it?